# What does the search domain in the network preferences do?

Tags: macos, network, dns, settings

I'm setting up my DNS to go through my employers DNS server and have entered the addresses they provided. They say it's a dynamic DNSSEC provider. I kind of understand this. But I noticed that under the search domains section to the right, there is an entry. What does the search domain for DNS do exactly? I would think my query, would go to the name-server I specified, and they would return the IP. How does this work exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has actually been answered in quite a bit of detail over on sister-site superuser.com, [here.](https://superuser.com/questions/184361/what-is-the-search-domains-field-for-in-the-tcp-ip-dns-settings-control-panel)

Comment: I see... so that's why it defaults to the IP address receiving local traffic on the router every time? Then the router must translate that to a FQDN, and then distributes the responses from the name-server queried by the machines on the network to the appropriate IP addrs in it's routing table... :) Bang! My apologies for my lack of googling and sincere thanks for pointing me to a clear explanation.

Comment: What that site doesn't answer, which might be more appropriate on the Apple-specific site here, is where that info gets stored in the Directory system on OS X (if that's where it goes) and how to query it from e.g. the command line.